# How do I get the size of a response from a Spring 2.5 HTTP remoting call?

Tags: java, http, spring, spring-remoting

I've been poking around the `org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker` package in Spring 2.5 trying to find a way to get visibility into the size of the response, but I keep going around in circles.

Via another question I saw here, I think what I want to do is get a handle on the `InputStream` that represents the response from the server, and then wrap it with an Apache commons-io `CountingInputStream`. What's the best way to go about doing this?

For the moment, I'd be happy with just printing the size of the response to stdout, but eventually I want to store it in a well-known location in my app for optional display.

Comment: Do you want to do this on the client, or on the server?

Comment: I would like to do this on the client ideally, but I suppose either client or server would work. I'm mainly interested in seeing the total traffic that comes back from the server after a request - if that's easier to do server-side than client-side, I'm OK with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking along the right lines, it just needs fleshing out with specifics. Brace yourself, I'm going to hit you with a bunch of long class names...

The client-side factory that generates the stub that talks to the remote service is `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean`. The superclass (`HttpInvokerClientInterceptor`) has a property called `httpInvokerRequestExecutor`, which defaults to an instance of `SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor`.

This is ripe for subclassing and extending; specifically it has a `decorateInputStream` method which you can use:

```
public class CountingHttpInvokerRequestExecutor extends SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor {
   @Override
   protected InputStream decorateInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
      return new CountingInputStream(super.decorateInputStream(is));
   }
}
```

And then inject that into the proxy factory:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="httpInvokerRequestExecutor">
        <bean class="com.mycompany.CountingHttpInvokerRequestExecutor"/>
    </property>
      <!-- Plus the various other properties required by HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean  -->
      <!-- URL, proxy interface, etc -->
</bean>
```

The trick then becomes to get hold of that information, which will require some creative rewiring. You could, for example, obtain the new instances of `CountingInputStream` from another factory somewhere, which would then expose the byte count to your user interface.

Comment: Hmm, someone's been mucking about with the code formatting on SO.... not an improvement...

Comment: Yeah, that "trick" is sort of the nut of the problem that I've been going around in my head about. I was trying to get it via override invoke() in an overridden HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean, but because of protected methods was not able to do that cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

The above was most of what I needed to do to get the Input/OutputStreams wired up. The last step to actually report the information involved overriding the commons-io CountingStreams' `close()` method to simply report the total bytes read/written during that session. I print that out using the log, and there we go! This has the drawback of not being able to match up the size to a particular service call, but perhaps some further overriding to the `SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor` could add some further logging, though this would require the logging occurred synchronously, which is a dubious assumption.